# Trailing navigation bar item inlined with the title

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, scrollview, navigationbar

Is it possible to achieve [such effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv8ET.jpg) with SwiftUI? I want custom view to be inlined with the navigationbartitle and for it to disappear on scroll

Comment: This is automatic behaviour of a `ScrollView` within a `NavigationView`.

Comment: @George_E the question is how to add an avatar view inlined with title